# What‘s the definition of static arbitrage?

Tags: arbitrage

Could someone give the strict definition of static arbitrage? I know what the arbitrage means but have no idea about the term "Static".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static arbitrage is an arbitrage that does not require any re-balancing of the portfolio. For example, the CME offers a mini euro future for 62,500 euros and a big euro future worth 125,000 euros. You could sell 1 big future and buy 2 mini futures and this would be a static arbitrage. Another example would be the forward price arbitrage.

A dynamic arbitrage is one in which you have to re-balance your portfolio. An example of this would be buying an under priced option in the perfect black-scholes world while continuously delta hedging.

Answer (score 7):

The definition of arbitrage can be broken down into categories such as:

1. A **static arbitrage** is an arbitrage that does not require rebalancing of positions.For example [static-arbitrage bounds](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1352&context=tepper) on the Prices of Basket Options
2. A **dynamic arbitrage** is an arbitrage that requires trading instruments in the future, generally contingent on market states.
3. A **statistical arbitrage** is a likely profit as predicted by past statistics.
4. **Model-independent arbitrage** does not depend on any mathematical model of financial instruments to work. An example of this would be a violation of Put-call parity.
5. **Model-dependent arbitrage** does require a model. An example would be options mispriced because of incorrect volatility.